# ubuntu "dummy output" for sound

Tags: 22.04, pulseaudio, soundcard

This commonly discussed problem of "dummy output" for the sound output device in ubuntu has affected me for a while now and I am not able to fix it.

I have tried many of the suggested solutions on `stackoverflow` and `askubuntu` but none of them have helped.

I am using Ubuntu 22 LTS. I noticed that whenever the "dummy output" exists one of the playback hardware device is missing. I found this out by running `aplay -l` and the outputs are shown below:

With sound working properly:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

When there is no sound ("dummy output"), then `ALC256 Analog` device is missing (`device 0` above) while the rest of the HDMI devices exist in the `aplay -l` output.

Can anyone kindly provide some hint or direction as to what is wrong here?